# Para que sirve el operador lógico ! delante de un objeto Java

Tags: java, poo

Estaba leyendo código y no he comprendido bien esta parte:

```
while(!hlpObj.isValid(choice));
```

No entiendo que hace el operador `!` delante del objeto `hlpObj`

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ! te permite indicar si es la negación.

```
/*
Recordando que .isValid te devuelve un booleanod True/False
podemos leer la instrucción:
Mientras  sea verdadero
*/
while(hlpObj.isValid(choice));

/*
El ! te permite evaluar/esperar la negacion del booleano resultante
podemos leer la instrucción:
Mientras  sea Falso
*/
while(!hlpObj.isValid(choice));
```

Saludos

Answer (score 6):

En Java como en muchos otros lenguajes, el `!`, es un operador lógico, en este caso un **operador lógico NOT** (negación) que se usa para revertir el valor, ejemplo:
devuelve false si el resultado es verdadero.

Este operador lógico se usa comunmente con una expresión boolean.
Como ejemplo la siguiente operación  `!(a == b)` , la cual dará como resultado `true` ya que a y b tienen valor diferente.

```
int a = 12;
int b = 5;
if( !(a == b) ) {
 //true
}else{
 //false
}
```

---

En el caso del ejemplo que mencionas, este método  `hlpObj.isValid(choice)` obtiene seguramente un valor de tipo `boolean` que al ser usado con el operador lógico !, indica que el bucle `while` se realizara siempre y cuando su valor sea `false` (ya que este será convertido a `true` )

```
while(!hlpObj.isValid(choice))
```

Revisa:

[Operadores lógicos.](https://es.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_booleanos)

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. Estoy empezando con la Poo ; y lo habia visto para numeros variables etc, pero no caí que también podría usarlo con objetos. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda a seguir aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Como te ha indicado el usuario más arriba:

```
while(!hlpObj.isValid(choice));
```

Sería lo mismo que poner

```
while(hlpObj.isValid(choice) == false);
```

Pero es más correcto además que queda un código más corto poniendolo de la primera forma. Quizás al principio te líe un poco más, pero una vez tengas eso claro es bastante sencillo y te darás cuenta de que queda un código más legible.